# jQuery validate not works with Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate

I can't get jQuery Validate working properly for Contact data properties of my Viewmodel due the generated names in the html does not match with the jQuery validate syntax.  If I use a `TextBoxFor` the html result for `Telephone` is `name="Contact.Telephone"`, but I can't set the rule as `Contact.Telephone`.

Am I missing something?

```
<input id="Contact_Telephone" class="form-control" type="text" value="" name="Contact.Telephone">  

 jQuery("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            Name: "required",
            LastName: "required",
            SecondLastName: "required",
            BirthDate: "required",
            Email: {
                email:true
            },
            Telephone: {
                digits: true,
                maxlength: 10
            },
            Mobile: {
                digits: true,
                maxlength: 10
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Name: "Dato requerido.",
            LastName: "Dato requerido.",
            SecondLastName: "Dato requerido.",
            BirthDate: "Dato requerido.",
            Email: {
                email: "Capture un correo válido."
            },
            Telephone: {
                digits: "Capture un dato numérico.",
                maxlength:"Longitud máxima permitida de 10 caractéres"
            },
            Mobile: {
                digits: "Capture un dato numérico.",
                maxlength: "Longitud máxima permitida de 10 caractéres"
            }
        }


public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int PersonID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set}
    public Datetime BirthDate {get;set;}
    public Contact Contact {get;set;}
}
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID {get;set;}
    public string Email {get;set;}
    public string Mobile {get;set;}
    public string Telephone {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Try adding the rule to the property `$( "#Contact_Telephone" ).rules( "add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Dato requerido" }});`

Comment: Why aren't you using Data annotations for validating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't get jQuery Validate working properly for Contact data properties of my Viewmodel due the generated names in the html do not match with the jQuery validate syntax.

They ***must*** match.  You must make them match or it will never work.

> ...the html result for Telephone is `name="Contact.Telephone"`, but I can't set the rule as `Contact.Telephone`

[When the `name` contains special characters like dots, you must use quotes around the `name`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots))...

```
jQuery("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        "Contact.Telephone": {
            digits: true,
            maxlength: 10
        }
        .....
```